# Error while changing the data type of the view column

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

```
create view [dbo].[view_name] as SELECT cast(Table1.col1 as bigint), Table1.col2, Table2.col3, cast(Table2.col4  as double)
FROM Table1 INNER JOIN
Table2 ON Table1.col1  = Table2.col1
```

Its showing error " error on ')'"

What is the error in the above query.I am using sql server 2008.

edit

```
create view [dbo].[SP_AHU_data] as SELECT cast(TrendLog.TrendLogId as bigint) as TrendLogid , TrendLog.TrendLogGuid, TrendLogValue.LogTime,cast(TrendLogValue.LogValue as double) as LogValue 
FROM TrendLog INNER JOIN
TrendLogValue ON TrendLog.TrendLogId = TrendLogValue.TrendLogId
where TrendLog.TrendLogGuid in('{DCCFB6EA-C606-4168-A2B3-FC1059173DAF}',
'{B1D5B0E8-44E2-459B-BC53-1CCE00FE7E6E}',
'{7493BB54-DC88-4ECF-81DA-3AEBCC698808}',
'{9641A376-D03D-46B7-9780-20DAC28AA3D9}')
```

There are two tables TrendLog and TrendLogValue

Trendlog has 2 columns

1. TrendLogId (PK,smallint notnull)
2. trendlogguid(uniqueidentifier not null)

trendLogValue has 3 columns

1. TrendLogId (PK,smallint notnull)
2. LogValue(float notnull)
3. LogTime(datetime notnull)

Comment: Describe tables using in views, please.

Answer (score 2):

Try to add aliases as below and change `double` to `float`

```
create view [dbo].[view_name] as 
SELECT cast(Table1.col1 as bigint) as col1, 
       Table1.col2, Table2.col3, 
       cast(Table2.col4  as float) as col4
FROM Table1 INNER JOIN
Table2 ON Table1.col1  = Table2.col1
```

**Sql fiddle [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/26f31/4/0)**

Double type is not sql server's type: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187752.aspx)

Comment: @user1896796 Can you describe table1 and table2?

Comment: Yes I saw, can you describe tables ?

Comment: why cant we change float to double ?

Comment: Because there is no `double` type: [MSND](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187752.aspx)